# How can I use a variable defined in an enclosed scope in other parts of my code? My code is pasted below

Tags: java, user-interface

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model1);
spinner.setBounds(101, 180, 61, 25);
spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        JSpinner s = (JSpinner)e.getSource();
        int val = (int) s.getValue();
    }
});
frame.getContentPane().add(spinner);
```

I want to use the variable `val` in other parts of my code which is outside its scope. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

A local variable used inside an inner class must be declared final, however you can use some kind of variable holder such as an array, Atomic classes, or your custom holder.

example:

```
int[] holder1 = new int[1];
AtomicReference<Integer> holder2 = new AtomicReference<>();
MyHolder<Integer> holder3 = new MyHolder<>();
var holder4 = new Object() { int value; }; // Java 10

JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model1);
spinner.setBounds(101, 180, 61, 25);
spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        JSpinner s = (JSpinner)e.getSource();
        int val = (int) s.getValue();

        holder1[0] = val;
        holder2.set(val);
        holder3.setValue(val);
        holder4.value = val;
    }
});
frame.getContentPane().add(spinner);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Piotr Żmudzin's solution is the way to go because variables captured in a closure are effectively final. But, it is worth noting that you are basically passing a function, or more specifically an anonymous object that contains a function. If you don't know when this passed function is called by the code you are passing it to, relying on the `holder.value` could be dangerous depending on where you use it. What you can do is add an additional member to a custom holder like this:

```
class MyHolder<T> 
{
    T value;
    boolean hasValue = false;
}
```

And now you can check if that variable has been set or not like this:

```
var holder1 = new MyHolder<Integer>(); 
var holder2 = new Object() { int value; boolean hasValue = false}; // Java 10

JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model1);
spinner.setBounds(101, 180, 61, 25);
spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        JSpinner s = (JSpinner)e.getSource();
        int val = (int) s.getValue();

        holder1.hasValue = true;
        holder1.value = val;
        holder2.hasValue = true;
        holder2.value = val;
    }
});
frame.getContentPane().add(spinner);

if (holder.hasValue) { 
   // use holder.Value 
}
```

Of course, this is not a problem if you exactly know when the function is called.